# Armadillo - delete rows in a cube

Tags: c++, armadillo

I'm using **Armadillo** C++ library for matrices.

I have a 3d matrix (Cube) of size [73 256 1000].

I would like to take only part of the rows of the cube, e.g. in matlab

```
A = A(3:66, :, :);
```

How can I do it with **Armadillo**? I haven't found anything in the API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality is listed in Armadillo's documentation, in the [subcube views](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#subcube) section. You can use *span::all* to indicate an entire range. to For example:

```
cube A(100,50,10);
A.randu();

A = A(span(3,66), span::all, span::all);
```